# My dryer stopped turning but still shakes when on and I think gives out heat

Tags: dryer

My Dryer inexplicably stopped turning. I went last night to switch it on and it doesnt turn anymore. The machine still shakes and I believe gets hot but it doesnt spin.

Someone mentioned something that maybe it is a snapped belt.

Is this for a layman or should I call a pro? 
What could the problem be?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it could be a snapped belt. It could also be a seized motor or a broken pulley.

The first thing I would do is look for disassembly instructions for your dryer. Some owners manuals include this, but for most you need to find the service manual. Come careful Googling with your model number may yield a PDF of the service manual.

Once you open the dryer, it will probably be obvious what the problem is.

From there you can order the part through the manufacturer or from someone else like http://www.repairclinic.com/. I've used them quite a few times.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. In that case, I am assuming that a pro isnt needed quite yet. Is it hard to replace the piece  once acquired?

Comment: It depends on a) which part is broken, b) the way the dryer is designed, and c) your skills and abilities. None of which we can gauge over the internet. If you figure out how to open the dryer, and you can tell easily what the problem is, then you will be able to gauge how easy it will be for you to do the work yourself. If at any point you feel you are in over your head, then it's simple to just put down your tools and call a pro.